# jquery fade in only on div

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fade, fadeout

this is my plugin:
http://www.clouderize.it/michele/261/

See the gallery under the post.

When I click on another image, a popup will appear. I would do the fade in and out only on the gallery, like here:

http://www.fanpage.it/foto/14n-guerriglia-urbana-a-roma/

Code: http://clouderize.it/cookie-localstorage/a.php

Plugin I use: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/
How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the div #overlay inside the container div #gallery-1. Its possible that you have to change some css but thats hard to tell without seeing all the code.